# C/C++ Functions - How are prototypes allowed?

Tags: c++, c, function, compiler-construction, prototype

Title.

Assuming(*because, as a beginner, I'm not sure*) a source code is read from top to bottom by the compiler. How does the compiler understand what actions are supposed to be performed when a function is called in the main function, if the said called function is not yet defined?

Thanks.

Comment: Admittedly a small difference between the questions (function defined in same/other file), but both asking how the compiler can use a function w/o having seen its definition.

Comment: Looking at the post that this is supposed to be a duplicate of and using it as a metaphor: The linker makes sure that the trouble I mentioned in my post doesn't happen? Does it practically relocate things in the code so that the compiler can read from top to bottom? If I haven't understood correctly, could you explain or let me try and get an answer from the forum?

Comment: No, as explained in the dupe, the compiler need not know what  the function does in the first place it. It only needs to know what arguments it takes and what it returns. But there's probably a better dupe for that I guess.

Comment: To call a function, all you need is its address ­-- once piece of information. (The prototype is just a safety measure) If a compiler doesn't have the address of a function named X, it will  (simplistically speaking) put "a blank for X" in it's object output and expect the linker to resolve it to an actual address. (The linker can resolve it from the same object file, from a different object file or from a library.)

Comment: "source code is read from top to bottom" - within _one_ source file. But C and C++ both have separate compilation. Lines in one file are neither below nor above lines in other files. You're looking at just the easy problem here.

Answer (score 1):

On most architectures, the assembly instructions required to call a function depend only on the number and type of arguments to that function, not how the function itself is implemented. In other words, calling any function that takes in an int and a double in that order requires the exact same sequence of assembly instructions.

When a compiler reads a function prototype, it typically won't generate any code and instead just makes a mental note to the effect of "okay, when I see someone call this function from this point forward, I'll know the number and types of the arguments that function expects so that I can generate the right code." For example, if it sees the prototype

```
 void doTheThing(int, double);
```

when it then sees the call

```
double x, y;
doTheThing(x, y);
```

it can generate code that evaluates x, narrows it to an integer, then (via some mechanism) stores the values of x and y as parameters to the function, invokes the function, then cleans up the parameters. The reason it knows to convert x to an int is that it saw the prototype, and based on how the architecture works it can then set up the mechanics to call the function.

In other words, the prototype itself doesn't generate any code. Instead, it informs the compiler how to generate code later on in a way that causes the arguments to get sent in and the return value extracted in the proper form and order.

Answer (score 0):

As an analogy: if you take a car into a repair shop, do you need to know in detail the full procedure the mechanic will use to diagnose and repair the problems?  No, all you need is information related to how you will interact with the repair shop: you need to drive your car in and eventually drive it out again, you should expect to pay money to them, they might provide a courtesy shuttle to and from your place of work, etc.

In a similar way, C/C++ compilers are able to generate machine code that hands off control of program execution from one function to another, and then once the called function has completed, resumes the execution of the original function where it left off.  All it needs to know is the interface of the function being called (specified through the prototype), not the full details of what it does.

(Of course, if the compiler does know the definition of the function being called, then it can optionally perform some optimizations based on that, up to "inlining" of the full function definition into the caller.  Similarly, if you know a bit about car repair, you might be able to do the repairs yourself for simple problems instead of taking it to a mechanic.)